# Leaving Comments

Tags: support, reputation, comments

I have 19 points on SO and see that I can't leave comments on questions that I did not originate or answer.  I thought it had something to do with my level, but then I noticed someone with less points leaving a comment.  Am I missing something?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Without a link to the question you are referring to it's hard to say why that would happen, but from the SO FAQ:

> 50     Leave comments

As already mentioned this does not apply to **our own questions and answers**.

Reasons why a user may have left a comment and now has low reputation would be:

- They got down-voted below the required 50 reputation,
- They set a bounty which dropped them below the required 50 reputation,
- They were suspended, which dropped them below the required 50 reputation

However at the time of leaving the comment they did meet the criteria.

Comment: I am terribly off today, it seems. Ah well. Kudos for indeed mentioning the two possible scenarios for a user to have <50 reputation yet still have a comment.

Comment: It's this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3677884/rotating-images. The comment is gone now, but the first comment on the original question appears to be in response to it.  The missing comment asked if it was possible to use jQuery.

Comment: @curt As I said. Without being able to see who posted the comment it's hard to say why. It is probably one of the reasons I have listed.

Comment: @Grace No Problem. I have been off most of the last few days to be honest. Glad I finally got one right.